# What part of speech is 'almost' in "these tiny flowers transform into pulp-filled pods almost the size of rugby balls"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, language-evolution

Now, before I get jumped on because *almost* is always an adverb, please allow me to explain.

If *almost* is an adverb, which it most definitely is (I checked several dictionaries and it is only listed as an adverb), then it must be modifying a verb, or an adjective or another adverb, but its relation is with the noun phrase *the size*, and really, so it seems, between *pods* and *the size*. Adverbs don't modify nouns. It appears to be functioning as a preposition, and indeed *about* or *around*, which are true prepositions, would produce equivalent meaning.

The only other option I can see is that *almost* is modifying the main verb *transform* which it is not - the flowers do not almost transform, they do indeed transform, so that cannot be the relation.

Ah, come to think of it, there does seem to be one more possibility, namely the demon ellipsis.

> These tiny flowers transform into pulp-filled pods (that are) almost
>   the size of rugby balls.

So, its a clause, where *almost* is modifying the elided verb. I think that's the answer but I still want to hear what folks have to say. Ellipsis seems to be a very strong factor in the evolution of grammar.

Some will say that adverbs can modify noun phrases, and some dictionaries do mention this use as rare but possible (e.g. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs)). However, dictionaries are hardly the arbiters of what is grammatical and others do not attribute this function to the adverb class (e.g. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/adverb) and [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/adverb?s=t). Some sidestep the issue by saying they can modify "phrases". Ha!

It sees a rather bold step to alter the class definition of adverbs with the function of the adjective class, which breaks the distinction, the very usefulness of classes, and seems wrong to me. It seems more fitting to broaden the scope of words, as they evolve in usage, to include another class function, such as *almost*, which seems to be commonly used as both a preposition and an adjective.

I'm quite stuck with this one. The use is quite common and undeniably well understood. Perhaps this is the language changing again, and it's time to reconsider the scope of this word to include a prepositional function. But maybe someone more knowledgeable than I has a better explanation.

Comment: If it were an adjective, it would have to read *the almost size of rugby balls*, which is wrong.

Comment: Adverbs can certainly modify NPs. "Almost" is an adverb modifying the NP (not a clause) "the size of rugby balls", which modifies "pods". (Btw, it's possible for adverbs to modify nouns, but it's rare)

Comment: @PeterShor - did I say it was an adjective? It does, however, seem to be an elliptic adjectival non-finite relative clause. You have a lot of point so I will defer to you. What do you think?

Comment: You didn't say it was an adjective, but you didn't explain why it wasn't, either. So I thought I'd add an explanation.

Comment: @PeterShor - granted that its function here is prepositional or adjectival with elision, but in other ways it is clearly used adjectivally (as a determiner) as in *Almost everyone enjoyed the show.*

Comment: It is not used adjectivally, and there's no ellipsis. "Almost" is a determinative used here as a modifier in the NP "almost the size of rugby balls". What relative clause? There isn't one. The NP functions as post-head modifier of "pods".

Comment: A determiner is, after all, a kind if adjective, and if it were elision, then it would be an adjectival clause. I  think the concepts or terms of analysis are useful when they reveal the intended meaning, there's little reason say one is correct and the others not. You seem to be saying that adverbs can modify nouns, which collapses the distinction the parts-of-speech provide, and that seems mistaken. Better I think, to broaden the scope of the word to include other word types, like preposition and adjective, than to redefine the adverb class. Words are fluid in this way, classes are not.

Comment: First, determiners determine; adjectives modify. Second, there's no such thing as an adjective clause. Third, I actually said that adverbs can modify **NPs**, not nouns, which they freely can (though they can, rarely, modify nouns). There's a difference!  "Almost" is an adverb functioning as modifier in the NP "almost the size of rugby balls", just as it is in "He ate **almost** the whole pie", and other similar examples.

Comment: The term adjective (or adjectival) clause is broadly used in the world of instructional grammar. Do a google search and you will see. Determiners are a sub-class of adjective, also broadly accepted. My contention is that if *almost* is functioning as modifier in the NP "almost the size of rugby balls", then it should not be classed as an adverb. I'm sure I'm not alone in this opinion.

Comment: "almost" is very clearly an adverb describing "to what degree" the pods are the size of rugby balls -- why is this not obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Original:  These tiny flowers transform into pulp-filled pods almost the size of rugby balls.

=> These tiny flowers transform into pulp-filled pods (that are) almost the size of rugby balls.

that are the size, that are exactly the size, that are almost the size

"Almost" is an adverb that answers the question "to what degree" are they the same size.

Comment: If an adverb by definition as a word class is a modifier of verbs, adjectives or adverbs - what then is it modifying in this sentence? So it seems you are agreeing with me (I said this in the OP). But if you read the comments you will see that not everyone agrees with this view that 'almost' is modifying an elided verb (be).

Comment: @UbuEnglish There are two views: **1.** "almost" is an adverb: "the size of rugby balls" is an adjectival phrase - this is not immediately apparent but the full phrase would be "***of*** the size of rugby balls", which is an adjectival phrase. **2.** An alternative view would be that "almost" is, as the OED says "**B. adj** Premodifying a noun or noun phrase: close to being (the thing mentioned). Cf. nearly adj. --1600   W. Shakespeare Much Ado about Nothing v. i. 114   You are almost come to parte almost a fray.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be helpful to look at a top-down analysis of the structure:

```
[sentence] --> [subject] [predicate]
[subject] --> [noun-phrase] ("...flowers")
[predicate] --> [verb-phrase] ("transform...")

[verb-phrase] --> [verb] [adverb]
[verb] = "transform"
[adverb] --> [prep-phrase] ("into...")

[prep-phrase] --> [preposition] [noun-phrase]
[preposition] = "into"
[noun-phrase] = "pods..."

[noun-phrase] --> [noun] [dependent-adj-phrase]
[noun] = "pods"
[dependent-adj-phrase] = "Ø Ø almost the size of rugby balls"
```

We just reached the grammatically tricky part:  the "zero" relative (i.e., an implicit "that/which are").

```
[dependent-adj-phrase] --> [relative-pronoun] [verb-phrase]
[relative-pronoun] = "Ø"
[verb-phrase] = "Ø almost the size of rugby balls"

[verb-phrase] --> [verb] [predicate-nominative]
[verb] = "Ø"
[predicate-nominative] = "...size..."

[predicate-nominative] --> [adverb] [determiner] [noun] [adj-phrase]
[adverb] = "almost"
[determiner] = "the"
[noun] = "size"
[adj-phrase] = "of rugby balls"
```

I think that is far enough to show how `almost` fits in and why and how it is an adverb.